# Windows 7/8 Wallpaper Registry Keys (Slideshow)

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-7, registry, wallpaper

I'm wondering where the registry keys are for the wallpaper locations, slideshow duration, and wallpaper fit so I can make a quick registry patch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find wallpaper location and wallpaper fit in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop.

The information about slideshow is not in Windows registry. You have to open path:

%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\

and make sure, that hidden files are visible (you can change that in folder options).

You can see slideshow.ini. There are tags for root slideshow image and slideshows.
I don't know how to decode it. Have fun :)

Comment: If it was what you were looking for, please, mark my response as answer. Thank you!

Comment: Just did. I couldn't figure it out at first ;)

Comment: Does anyone anywhere know how to decode this?

Comment: Thank you very much! I've deleted the Wallpaper key by mistake and couldn't find it again

Answer (score 5):

There is a **registry entry** which contains (but not controls) **the current slideshow duration in miliseconds**. It is

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Personalization\Desktop Slideshow\Interval
```

You can change it, but the next time you use the theme, the duration will be 15 minutes again.
That **duration is copied from**:

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\<i>Themes\theme_name\theme_name.theme</i>
```

(a text file) where there is an item named ***Interval*** near the end of the file.
You can **change the value of that entry to**, say:

```
Interval=14400000
```

which is **4 hours**, or any other value. But **I do not know where the 15 minutes duration comes initially from**.